# Having trouble creating a MySQL database with python

Tags: python, mysql, database

I can't seem to figure out why my code won't create a MySQL table.
Everything seems ok to me, although my knowledge is limited.

```
import mysql.connector
import bot_keys as bk

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
  host = bk.dbHost,
  user = bk.dbUser,
  password = bk.dbPass,
  database = bk.dbName
)

mycursor = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    sql_fs1 = ("SET SQL_MODE = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';"
               "SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;START TRANSACTION;"
               "SET time_zone = '+00:00';"
               "CREATE TABLE `test_table`(`id` int(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY "
                  "AUTO_INCREMENT,`date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT "
                  "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`test_info` "
                  "varchar(10) NOT NULL,`xxx` varchar(255) NOT NULL);")
    mycursor.execute(sql_fs1, multi=True)
    conn.commit()

create_table()
```

Can anyone point out where I am failing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what happens when you run this?

Comment: Nothing, no errors from python and no table created.

Answer (score 0):

I would first check to see if your connection is actually working...

```
if conn.is_connected():
        db_Info = conn.get_server_info()
        print("Connected to MySQL Server version ", db_Info)
```

This assumes your bot keys have been properly parameter-ized, if i were you I would attempt to initially run w hard coded values, then parameter-ize once youve successfully run things....

Comment: Bot keys are fine, have tried hard coding them.
Can't get the table created either way...

Comment: and what happens when you run the code snippet I sent you? Youre not going to be able to make a table if you cant connect............

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I get:
Connected to MySQL Server version  5.5.5-10.1.28-MariaDB

Answer (score -1):

The error will go away if you delete the line

```
conn.commit
```

The create table command causes an implicit commit,
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, there is still no table and no error code when i remove the conn.commit()

Comment: Then there is probably something wrong with your database connection because it worked for me that way. Have you tried to directly execute your SQL string on your MySQL server (without Python)? What happens when you execute a simpler command in your code (e.g. fetch something from an existing table or create a minimalistic one) - does that work?

Comment: Well I'm completely baffled, the command runs fine directly in mysql and creates the table... I'll have a fiddle and see where I can get. Thanks for your time!